# How can I attach an avatar to a JIRA user manually (through API or database operations)?

Tags: jira, avatar, atlassian-crowd

We are using JIRA 4.4 with crowd.

We want to dump users photos from Active Directory into the avatar folder (inside jira-home directory) and than to automatically associate those photos with JIRA users (we don't want each and every user having to manualy choose their avatar).

Can this be done through database insert/update operations?

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not be too helpful but have you already looked into [this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/38673/avatar-upload-with-jira-5-rest-api)? The only problem is that the REST API for managing avatars was introduced in JIRA 5.0+

I'm not aware of a easy way of doing it on JIRA 4.4 unfortunately.